# Changing cursor style of atom editor

Tags: css, json, atom-editor

Hello is there a way to change the caret style of atom just like in sublime text 3? The way sublime text 3 did it was this way in the settings JSON `"caret_style": "phase"`

Is there a way to do something just like this in atom editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `.atom/styles.less` (or `~/.atom/stylesheet.css`), add/update the following transition to `atom-text-editor .cursor`:

```
atom-text-editor .cursor {
  transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

If you want to update cursor speed, you can get [`cursor-blink-interval`](https://atom.io/packages/cursor-blink-interval) package and update the following in your `.atom/config.cson` :

```
'*':
  'cursor-blink-interval':
    cursorBlinkInterval: 1200
```

See also [block-cursor](https://atom.io/packages/block-cursor) package

Comment: may I ask if there is a difference between them? I opted out for the first one so thank you.

Comment: Between [cursor-blink-interval](https://atom.io/packages/cursor-blink-interval) & [block-cursor](https://atom.io/packages/block-cursor) ? cursor-blink-interval is just for setting the cursor blink speed while block-cursor is for personnalizing the cursor style (and can set the cursor speed as well with `pulseDuration`)

Comment: ah thanks for this but I think that those two packages are too complicated for me to use but can `cursor-blink-interval` be used together with the .cursor fix you posted. because I think the phasing right now is too fast for my taste.

Comment: Yes just add `'cursor-blink-interval':
    cursorBlinkInterval: 1200` in the `'*'` section

Comment: That's perfect :)