# How do I change the mouse cursor in Atom?

Tags: cursor, styles, atom-editor

I'm using Atom 1.15.0 on Mac Sierra.  I wanted to change the mouse cursor from a thin bar to something more visible, like a block.  I opened my styles.less file and added

```
atom-text-editor .cursor {
  transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

and then restarted Atom, but my mouse cursor appears as before (a thin line).  How do I change it?

**Edit:** INcluding my styles.less file

```
/*
 * Your Stylesheet
 *
 * This stylesheet is loaded when Atom starts up and is reloaded automatically
 * when it is changed and saved.
 *
 * Add your own CSS or Less to fully customize Atom.
 * If you are unfamiliar with Less, you can read more about it here:
 * http://lesscss.org
 */


/*
 * Examples
 * (To see them, uncomment and save)
 */

// style the background color of the tree view
.tree-view {
  // background-color: whitesmoke;
}

// style the background and foreground colors on the atom-text-editor-element itself
atom-text-editor {
  // color: white;
  // background-color: hsl(180, 24%, 12%);
}

// style UI elements inside atom-text-editor
atom-text-editor .cursor {
  transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.editor .cursor {
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid;
   background-color: rgba(244,100,122,0.6);
}

atom-text-editor .editor-contents--private { cursor: default; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would direct you to this package:

https://atom.io/packages/block-cursor

Also: [Changing cursor style of atom editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468937/changing-cursor-style-of-atom-editor)

**Update:**

These properties should apply to the mouse cursor as they do with the text cursor. As long as they're directed properly.

*Try Adding this to the StyleSheet:*

`atom-text-editor .editor-contents--private { 
   cursor: default; 
   position: absolute; 
   border: 1px solid;
   background-color: rgba(244,100,122,0.6);
   }`

Comment: What's hte shortcut for installing a package on Atom?

Comment: I believe it's `ctrl + , ` which brings up the settings and then you can select the `packages` tab on the left and search for the package from there. You can also try pressing `ctrl + shift + P` and the dropdown menu will appear and then you  can type in the keywords: `install packages` and you should see an option to install packages. :D

Comment: You can also go to `file menu--> settings` and select the packages tab

Comment: If it works, feel free to mark this answer as a solution

Comment: As netizen points out, you're referring to the text cursor, right?  My question deals with the mouse cursor.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Insert this into your styles.less

```
atom-text-editor .editor-contents--private { cursor: default; }
```

Comment: THat didn't do it.  Maybe I didn't put the lines where you wanted?  I include my entire styles.less file in my question.

Comment: I know something has changed between versions 1.15 and 1.17 that may cause that. Try to open dev-tools:
Menu->View->Developer->Toggle developer tools, and then inspect any line in your editor. Now try inspecting parent elements until you find the cursor attribute, which will give you the correct selctor to place in your styles.less

Comment: I did as you said but I don't 'know how ot inspect the style that generates the mouse cursor.

Comment: Instead of inspecting parent elements: Just switch in the tools to the "Computed styes" tab in the right pane. Look for cursor there and you'll get pointers to where they are adefined. Use the selector from those, your styles.less will override it.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment -- "Just switch in the tools to the "Computed styes" tab".  All the tabs I have up are the files I have open.  Also, I don't see a "Tools" menu in my menu bar.

Comment: On the right side of the developer tools, after selecting any element from the editor, there will be a column with the CSS attributes of the selected element. At the top of that column there's a "computed" tab. Scroll to cursor and expand. An arrow in a solid circle will open where the current cursor definition is.

Comment: Did you test with cursor: default before going on with transition? Edit: Also, as I'm unable to comment to the other answer, those packages deal with the text cursor, not the mouse one

Answer (score 0):

```
    atom-text-editor {
  cursor: url(/home/thedude/Pictures/ico/octocat_mini.png), auto;
    }
```

[Atom with Octocat mouse pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNylk.jpg)

I can confirm that this line allows for the mouse cursor to be changed, but only when in the editor or in search boxes ,etc. The typing cursor is the purple thingie after the } at the end.